# change css depending of the number of occurrences

Tags: css

I want to style the user div depending on the number of times the user class 
appears in the parent class. I know how to do this with jquery but is this possible with css3 only? I only target Chrome browser.

```
<div class="parent">
 <div class="user"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
 <div class="user"></div>
 <div class="user"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a selector called :nth-child(integer). You can do it as such

```
.parent .user:nth-child(1)
```

Will only affect the first .user inside that .parent. I don't know why it's not 0 based, but whatever. Also, you can use equations, such as

```
.parent .user:nth-child(2n+2)
```

Which will only select every second .parent .user

Here's some more reading

http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Or to show style based on how many times .user shows up, there's the solution of styling 1st child, then overriding it, while styling 2nd child, and overwriding that when styling 3rd and so on. Here's an example

http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/

Comment: I don't think I can use the nth-child selector since it only selects one div in the parent class I want to style depending the number of user divs in the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of doing what you're asking that I'm aware of. The method linked to by Gareth Parker requires you to either know how many child elements there will be or know the maximum number of them.

The closest I got was to style any `.user` elements that succeed one `.user` element:

```
​.parent .user { background:red; }
.parent .user ~ .user { background:blue; }
```

​
This uses the `~` combinator, which is the General Sibling combinator.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/bBcMm/) it is in action.

You could also, of course, apply a class to any `.parent` elements that you know will have more than one `.user` element inside, then just target any `.user` elements within that given class.